# autofilter using double variable criteria vba

Tags: excel, vba, double, autofilter

So I need to filter all the prices less or equal than the value of the cell(6,3) (which is 50.60).

This is my code, but for some reason it just doesn't work for double values. For instance, if I change the value of the cell(6.3) from 50.60 to 50, the code works just fine.

Any tips?

```
Sub cost()

Dim price As Double

'Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
'Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","
'Application.UseSystemSeparators = True

Range("B2:C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

price = Cells(6, 3).Value

 Range("A1:C1").Select
 Selection.AutoFilter
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$12").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$12").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=" & price
End Sub
```

This is my worksheet:

```
hour consumption    price
1    20,50          0,00
1    50,10          1,30
1    70,60          1,50
1    10,70         30,60
1    15,90         50,60
1    30,80         56,20
1    60,30         60,30
2    45,20          0,00
2    80,60         11,30
2    50,70         20,40
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can't tell without more testing, but is VBA interpreting your decimal separator as desired, so 50,60 is being interpreted as 50 decimal 6 ?  What are your country/language settings?

Comment: My country/language settings is Portuguese(PT). I think the problem is VBA is not interpreting correctly the value of cells(6,3). But for example, if  I test msgbox(price) it gives me the correct value.

I've already tried to change the Decimal.Separator from "," to ".", but it didn't work either:\

Comment: I see you have a solution. Boa sorte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line it works for me. All you just have to do is converting `price` to `string` before you concatenate it to `"<="`.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$12").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=" & Str(price)
```

Comment: Károly Szommer, thanks man!!That was it, now it works just fine:)